# httpd server not loading sending web page

Tags: php, apache

I am running an linux server amazon EC2 instance.

The httpd server was fine and I just checked and is no longer working. I am not sure what happened. It is not giving out any output.

Log at end of question...

- The log doesn't appear to have any information related to error in load content on requests.
  I am using a log file located here: /etc/httpd/logs/error_log is there another one?

I had a few virtual servers that redirect subdomains which were working, I temporarily removed them incase they are related to the issue.

I have restart the httpd server a few times and still nothing.

Also my www directory has an index.php and i put a index.html in there for good luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:18 2012] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:18 2012] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 256 bytes of entropy
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:18 2012] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [info] mod_ssl/2.2.9 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.9, Library: OpenSSL/0.9.8b
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [notice] Digest: done
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] util_ldap.c(1977): LDAP merging Shared Cache conf: shm=0x8009e420 rmm=0x8009e450 for VHOST: domU-12-31-39-0A-1D-16.compute-1.internal
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [info] APR LDAP: Built with OpenLDAP LDAP SDK
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [info] LDAP: SSL support available
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/memcache.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/memcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'gd' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/modules/memcache.so' - /usr/lib/php/modules/memcache.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [info] Init: Seeding PRNG with 256 bytes of entropy
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [info] Init: Generating temporary RSA private keys (512/1024 bits)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [info] Init: Generating temporary DH parameters (512/1024 bits)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(374): shmcb_init allocated 512000 bytes of shared memory
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(554): entered shmcb_init_memory()
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(576): for 512000 bytes, recommending 4266 indexes
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(619): shmcb_init_memory choices follow
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(621): division_mask = 0x1F
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(623): division_offset = 64
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(625): division_size = 15998
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(627): queue_size = 1604
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(629): index_num = 133
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(631): index_offset = 8
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(633): index_size = 12
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(635): cache_data_offset = 8
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(637): cache_data_size = 14386
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] ssl_scache_shmcb.c(650): leaving shmcb_init_memory()
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [info] Shared memory session cache initialised
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [info] Init: Initializing (virtual) servers for SSL
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [info] mod_ssl/2.2.9 compiled against Server: Apache/2.2.9, Library: OpenSSL/0.9.8b
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 14136 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 14136 for (*)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 14137 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 14137 for (*)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 14138 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 14138 for (*)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 14138 for (*)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 14139 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 14139 for (*)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 14140 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 14140 for (*)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 14141 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 14141 for (*)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 14142 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 14142 for (*)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1854): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 14143 for worker proxy:reverse
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1873): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1967): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 14143 for (*)
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.9 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.2.6 mod_ssl/2.2.9 OpenSSL/0.9.8b configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [info] Server built: Jul 14 2008 15:29:50
[Wed Apr 25 10:50:19 2012] [debug] prefork.c(1001): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
```

Comment: I feel like an idiot... A few months ago I changed my local firewall to be more secure and it was blocking the port(8080) I was trying to connect to. 

Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an idiot...

A few months ago I changed my local firewall to be more secure and it was blocking the port(8080) I was trying to connect to.

Thanks anyways.